# How can i move my layout via accelerometer sensor?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I've two `AbsoluteLayout` are called `Background_layout` and `Foreground_layout` in one base XML.

I wanna move first layout (`Background_layout`) through the accelerometer sensor for direction Y X Z , How can i do that?

Here you can see my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background_layout" 
android:background="@drawable/background" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>
<AbsoluteLayout 
android:id="@+id/foreground_layout" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/foreground" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_x="0dip" 
android:layout_y="0dip">
</AbsoluteLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I have all the values about direction , But I don't know How can I use them in layout view.

```
 public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    synchronized (this) {
    if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
    float ValuX = (float) values[0];
    float ValuY = (float) values[1];
    float ValuZ = (float) values[2];
    int ResValuX  = new Integer(Float.toString(ValuX));
    int ResValuY  = new Integer(Float.toString(ValuY));
    int ResValuZ  = new Integer(Float.toString(ValuZ));
    Background.addView(Background,ResValuX);
    Background.addView(Background,ResValuY);
    Background.addView(Background,ResValuZ);
    }
    }
    }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You know that with the hundreds of different types of Android devices, AbsoluteLayout will not work?

Comment: @Jack : Really ? So what is your suggestion?

Comment: RelativeLayout, or any other layout besides Absolute. With the many different screen sizes, AbsoluteLayout may work great on your development device, but when I put it on my 10.1 inch tablet it may not. Anyway I did not mean to deter you from your original question, just wanted to let you know that :).

Comment: @Jack : Thanks Jack, Well I did not know that Thanks for informing me . Now back to my problem  , How can I do that?

Comment: Ok please clarify what you mean "move first layout THROUGH the accelerometer" sensor? Do you mean move it according to values from the sensor?

Comment: I actually see two different questions, 1 how to read the sensor? 2 how to move/reposition a layout? If your question is different from both, please include more details or where exactly you're having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get values from the accelerometer, then you can update the postition of views by setting their layout parameters. To move the views to left, you could set the value as the left margin.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.leftMargin = 10;
view.setLayoutParameters(lp);
```

This should work.